# Tor 8 no longer has Green Onion with option to change circuitcharley

Tags: circuit

My PC auto-updated to Tor 8 and I no longer have the green onion on the left side of the browser where I can check my circuit or change to a new circuit. Can I roll back to an earlier version of Tor that allows me the functionality I seem to have lost?

Answer (score 1):

Circuit information is now shown within individual tabs by clicking the "i" object at the far left of the address or URL bar.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Why changing one of the most useful tool in Tor to put it in an almost invisible place? Besides, many ip adresses used by Tor are censored and blocked by the gestapo (google so called captcha), the stasi (cloudflare challenges) and their stooges (other big techs destroying your privacy or so called 'cybersecurity' companies like nginx who are just censoring agents). Many sites are just not accessible with Tor anymore as a result + it seems many sites can identify who you are despite having the highest and strictest privacy settings on Tor.... So, at least, having some kind